# Extract a link with Nokogiri from the text of link?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I want to extract a specific link from a webpage, searching for it by its text, using Nokogiri:

```
<div class="links">
   <a href='http://example.org/site/1/'>site 1</a>
   <a href='http://example.org/site/2/'>site 2</a>
   <a href='http://example.org/site/3/'>site 3</a>
</div>
```

I would like the href of "site 3" and return:

```
http://example.org/site/3/
```

Or I would like the href of "site 1" and return:

```
http://example.org/site/1/
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you want a substring search or exact match?

Comment: Both. This case it was for exact match, but I would like know how search (get) href which text will start by "site" for instance too. In a case where not all text of link are "site".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Original:**

```
text = <<TEXT
<div class="links">
  <a href='http://example.org/site/1/'>site 1</a>
  <a href='http://example.org/site/2/'>site 2</a>
  <a href='http://example.org/site/3/'>site 3</a>
</div>
TEXT

link_text = "site 1"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(text)
p doc.xpath("//a[text()='#{link_text}']/@href").to_s
```

**Updated:**

As far as I know Nokogiri's XPath implementation doesn't support regular expressions, for basic `starts with` matching there's a function called `starts-with` that you can use like this (links starting with "s"):

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(text)
array_of_hrefs = doc.xpath("//a[starts-with(text(), 's')]/@href").map(&:to_s)
```

Comment: And for instance, if I would like get all href which text starts with "s" or "si" ... (regex). How can I do?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you will like css style selection better:

```
doc.at('a[text()="site 1"]')[:href] # exact match
doc.at('a[text()^="site 1"]')[:href] # starts with
doc.at('a[text()*="site 1"]')[:href] # match anywhere
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'nokogiri'

text = "site 1"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(DATA)
p doc.xpath("//div[@class='links']//a[contains(text(), '#{text}')]/@href").to_s
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to document another way we can do this in Ruby, using the URI module:

```
require 'uri'

html = %q[
<div class="links">
    <a href='http://example.org/site/1/'>site 1</a>
    <a href='http://example.org/site/2/'>site 2</a>
    <a href='http://example.org/site/3/'>site 3</a>
</div>
]

uris = Hash[URI.extract(html).map.with_index{ |u, i| [1 + i, u] }]

=> {
    1 => "http://example.org/site/1/'",
    2 => "http://example.org/site/2/'",
    3 => "http://example.org/site/3/'"
}

uris[1]
=> "http://example.org/site/1/'"

uris[3]
=> "http://example.org/site/3/'"
```

Under the covers [URI.extract](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-extract) uses a regular expression, which isn't the most robust way of finding links in a page, but it is pretty good since a URI usually is a string without whitespace if it is to be useful.